# Can I listen to Air Traffic Control on a flight?

Tags: air-travel, safety, airlines

What airlines have an audio channel where you can listen to Air Traffic Control communications during the flight? Do any airlines allow you to bring a scanner or aviation radio aboard to listen yourself?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only one I'm aware of is United Airlines, on Channel 9; this appears to be disappearing rapidly as Continental did not have it.

Radios are never permitted in flight.

However, there are [websites with live ATC feeds](http://www.liveatc.net/) so if the flight had WiFi you might be able to listen through a computer. I have used the iOS app version of LiveATC to listen to traffic control using inflight wifi; this only works over 10,000 feet when the wifi is on and you have to know the frequency that your cockpit crew happens to be on.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember a United flight from LA to Denver in 2000 that I was on, storm approaching and the various convos they were having about avoiding it.  Since working in Air Traffic Control software development, I no longer have a desire to do so - 99% of the talk is mundane and stuffed with acronyms and just messages and acknowledgements.  Suppose it's that 1% that might be 'interesting' for want of a better word ;)

Comment: @Mark: Well, one man's mundane is another man's interesting :) Off topic, but what language is ATC software written in?

Comment: True, and even this was interesting at first, but now it just sounds like work ;)

Comment: The majority of the code I worked with was C++, and some proprietary scripting tools as well.

Comment: Not all of them do. I once rode on a United Boeing 737-800 with the DIRECTV In-Flight system and it did not have it. (AFAIK, it's only because of its acquisition of Continental that it started having 737s in its fleet.)